# GET API request - sub documents

Tags: python, api, get

so I'm currently creating the backend API for a project. The project has a database that stores posts. Each post has a nested array for comments, and the comments array has another nested array for replies. I've created a GET request to retrieve all replies under a certain comment, however, the same replies are appearing under every comment. Can anyone spot what is wrong with the code?

Backend code:

```
def fetch_all_replies(id, comment_id):

    data_to_return = []
    post = posts.find_one(

    )
        for comment in post["comments"]:
            comment["_id"] = str(comment["_id"])
            for reply in comment["replies"]:
                reply["_rid"] = str(reply["_rid"])
            data_to_return.append(reply)
    return make_response( jsonify( data_to_return), 200 )
```

Database structure:

```
 [
    {
        "_id": "63f4cbb5462827492d6ee419",
        "description": "Join us on a hike of cake hill to see the stunning sunrise!!",
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "63f7ba0deca5ad33c3c18ed0",
                "comment": "is this park dog friendly?",
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "_rid": "63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c",
                        "comment": "Yeah, this park is dog friendly!",
                        "username": "Beth"
                    }
          
    
   ]
```

So if i run the request 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/posts/63f4cbb5462827492d6ee419/comments/63f9ee3194ea5d46da5472c6' I get:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63f9ee3194ea5d46da5472c6",
        "comment": "Do i need much experience to do this hike?",
        "replies": [
            {
                "_rid": "63ff744d03b399e52def7d3d",
                "comment": "Yes, i'm brining my spring spaniel ",
                "username": "sarah"
            }
        ],
        "username": "Rachel"
    }
]
```

But if I run 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/posts/63f4cbb5462827492d6ee419/comments/63f9ee3194ea5d46da5472c6/replies', I am returned with:

```
[
    {
        "_rid": "63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c",
        "comment": "Yeah, this park is dog friendly!",
        "username": "Beth"
    },
    {
        "_rid": "63ff74de03b399e52def7d3e",
        "comment": "This is my first hike",
        "username": "Anna"
    },
    {
        "_rid": "63ff752a03b399e52def7d3f",
        "comment": "I've hiked up cave hill several times!",
        "username": "Juno"
    },
    {
        "_rid": "63ff744d03b399e52def7d3d",
        "comment": "Yes, i'm brining my spring spaniel ",
        "username": "sarah"
    }
]
```

Comment: `data_to_return.append(reply)` reply gets overwritten by the `for` loop. So you are appending only the last reply.

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Append each reply within the for loop:

```
post = {
        "_id": "63f4cbb5462827492d6ee419",
        "description": "Join us on a hike of cake hill to see the stunning sunrise!!",
        "comments": [{
            "_id": "63f7ba0deca5ad33c3c18ed0",
            "comment": "is this park dog friendly?",
            "replies": [{
                    "_rid": "63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c",
                    "comment": "Yeah, this park is dog friendly!",
                    "username": "Beth"
                },
                {
                    "_rid": "63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c",
                    "comment": "Yeah, this park is cat friendly!",
                    "username": "Beth"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }

data_to_return = []
for comment in post["comments"]:
    comment["_id"] = str(comment["_id"])
    for reply in comment["replies"]:
        reply["_rid"] = str(reply["_rid"])
        data_to_return.append(reply)
print(data_to_return)
```

Out:

```
[
    {'_rid': '63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c', 'comment': 'Yeah, this park is dog friendly!', 'username': 'Beth'}, 
    {'_rid': '63f7fe6e16423c052a18cf8c', 'comment': 'Yeah, this park is cat friendly!', 'username': 'Beth'}
]
```

Comment: This works great! The only issue is, it's displaying the same replies, no matter the comment

Comment: @BethMcCoy: Whats your expected output, please edit your question ?

Comment: Updated now, hopefully that's clearer :)